# DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 7 day) .... am I wrong?

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to SELECT between CURRENT_DATE() and the last 7 days...So, this is what I got so far :

```
SELECT *
FROM `formulaires`.`summary`
WHERE (Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 7 day) AND CURRENT_DATE());
```

So..yah, this aint working properly. Any suggestions ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM `formulaires`.`summary`
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 7 day) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

(include "interval")